# Can invisible Java Applets in google chrome using JRE 7u51

Tags: java, google-chrome, applet, japplet, signed-applet

Can not visible Java Applets in Google chrome while calling it from HTML file?  But it runs fine in Internet explorer and Mozilla Firefox, while see the source of the page in Google Chrome it      shown the applet code  is called. Now where and what should I change to run applets in Google Chrome? (Chrome does not show any error, only grey screen appears.)

My applet element in HTML page is:

```html
<applet id= "myApplet" width=850 height=650>
<param name=CODE value=pkg.myApplet.class >
<param name=ARCHIVE value=/Jar/myApplet.jar >
<param name=USER_CD value=username >
<param name=OTHER value=other >
<param name=JAVA_ARGUMENTS value="-Xmx128m">
<param name=CODEBASE_LOOKUP value="false">
</applet>
```

Comment: *"Can invisible Java Applets in google chrome using JRE 7u51"* I changed 'visible' to 'invisible' in the title to match *"Can not visible Java Applets.."* in the body.  Now I'm wondering if you mean the opposite, given a 850x650 size and 'grey screen'..  Is this applet *supposed* to be visible to the user?  If not, how is it being hidden?

Comment: BTW - The ***best*** way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).